# tflite: Make multiple invocations at once

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Assume a webpage where multiple users send an image at once for inference. One option is to load the tflite model for each inference call by loading it inside the function

```
def detect_from_image(image_path):
    # load model
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="detect.tflite")
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # set input tensor
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img)

    # run
    interpreter.invoke()

    # get outpu tensor
    boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

The drawback above is the model is loaded separately for each call.

Loading the model outside the function

```
# load model
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="detect.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

 
def predict(image_path):
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # set input tensor
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img)

    # run
    interpreter.invoke()

    # get outpu tensor
    boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

When the model is loaded outside the function like above, it does not seem to work when multiple calls are made at the same time as interpreter.set_tensor and invoke() are not producing any output but replacing the tensors internally.

Is there any functionality like below to make it work for parallel calls?

```
def predict(image_path):
        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    
        # set input tensor
        new_tensor = interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], img)
    
        # run
        output = interpreter.invoke(new_tensor)
    
        # get outpu tensor
        boxes = output.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider having a pool for storing TFLite interpreter instances and picking up one instance per request. TFLite interpreter API does not guarantee the multi-thread support.